# R: show result of calculation in command line

Tags: r, command-line

In matlab, if you leave the ; out, you get the result printed in the command center. For r, is there a little trick other than pasting the left hand side variable again in the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclose your calculation in a parenthesis

```
(a <- 1:3)
[1] 1 2 3
```